# Is there any country that gives tax residency without living there?

Tags: taxes, tax-residency, argentina

Is there any country that gives tax residency without the need to live there for most of the year? Most countries I've read about need you to live there a substantial part of the year (among other requirements in many cases).

An occasional visit to such country would be acceptable.

In case someone wonders why, the reason for this is that Argentina has high taxes and you've got to pay taxes for your assets independently from where they are located.
Since I've got assets in other countries I pay my Argentina's elevated taxes for those assets, which wouldn't pay as much taxes if I lived in the other country.

I want to do what's called "loosing tax residency". This has one simple requirement by law: get tax residency somewhere else. I don't want to live somewhere else, but I'd like to avoid paying taxes for assets outside my country.

Comment: Your country is under no obligation to recognize the other country's claim to sole tax residency. If you fit *your* country's definition of "tax resident", they're going to tax you, unless they have a special agreement with the tax-shelter country, and I have a hard time believing they would give up the tax revenue by doing that.

Comment: My country's law states: "tax residency will be lost when an individual gets a permanent tax residence in some other country, according to such country's law".

Comment: Which country is that? A valid answer can't simply take your word on the interpretation of the law of an anonymous country.

Comment: From the [taxes] tag wiki: "Whenever asking about taxes, please also specify a country tag such as united-states, canada, united-kingdom, etc. "

Comment: @chepner Sorry, I missed that. Here's a link to our "IRS" stating what I just mentioned: [AFIP](https://www.afip.gob.ar/genericos/guiavirtual/consultas_detalle.aspx?id=1245395)

Comment: By the way, even if my interpretation of Argentina's law is wrong I'd like to know if there is any country that gives tax residency without living there.

Comment: Is "tax residency" and "permanent residency" really the same thing? That link doesn't mention tax liability explicitly. Nothing there suggests to me (I'm neither a lawyer nor proficient in Spanish, relying on Google Translate) that establishing permanent residency outside of Argentina gets you off the hook for paying Argentine taxes. (I'm assuming you are a citizen of Argentina.)

Comment: I consulted lawyers about that. I am a citizen of Argentina, as well as of other 2 countries. I've can get permanent residency in both of those, it's not what I need, I need tax residency, which is not exactly the same. That site apparently forgot to mention "tax" in the "permanent residency", which might be implicit, since its a tax agency.

Comment: OK, I'll shut up now :)

Comment: Oh, I hope you didn't take anything I said in a bad way, it wasn't meant to offend you in any way. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Nope, just pushing through my own ignorance to make sure that the question you are asking is really relevant to  your apparent goal :)

Comment: United States citizens are obligated to file tax returns, and in some cases pay income tax, even if they never live in the US. See https://money.stackexchange.com/q/55421/34875 and https://money.stackexchange.com/a/22931/34875 . Is that the sort of thing you're asking about?

Comment: Not exactly. I have to pay taxes in Argentina if my fiscal residence is here. If I get my fiscal residence somewhere else I can resign my fiscal residence here. I want to know if there is some country that gives fiscal residence without living there. If I go to live to a certain country I'll get the fiscal residence in that country for almost all (if not all) countries.

Comment: Are you saying that Argentina will allow you to not be considered resident for tax purposes as long as you say you are resident for tax purposes somewhere else, even if you actually live in Argentina?

Comment: Not say, but obtain and show proof that I am. Although I wouldn't be surprised if the tax agency doesn't abide by the law and decides that I can't do it, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Just because you are considered resident in one country for tax purposes does not mean another country will not also consider you resident there for tax purposes.**

Countries set their own rules for when you are considered a tax resident, and they don't consider whether or not you are also resident elsewhere. So if you were to find another country that would let you be a tax resident there without actually living there, Argentina would still consider you a tax resident there and make you pay taxes.

For example the UK considers you to be a tax resident if you spend six months in Britain in the tax year (April->March). Canada considers you resident there if you spend six months in Canada during the calendar year. If you move from Canada to the UK in September you satisfy both requirements and you are resident in both countries for tax purposes. Neither country considers you not resident there just because you are also resident in the other.

Comment: No, not just because. It's because of the law of the first country. It has some quirks which will make me be a tax resident in Argentina for a while, even if I move to live definitively somewhere else. But this doesn't really answer the question, which is: Is there a country that could accept me as a tax resident without me living (like in Canada and UK example) there?

Answer (score 1):

According to [OECD – Argentina – Information on residency for tax purposes](https://www.oecd.org/tax/automatic-exchange/crs-implementation-and-assistance/tax-residency/Argentina_Tax_Residency.pdf):

> An individual **is** considered a resident, **even if** he/she has obtained
>   the permanent residence in a foreign country, or has **lost its
>   residence status in the Argentine Republic because the person is
>   regarded as resident of another country for tax purposes**, when they
>   actually live in the national territory or reenter the country [Argentina] in
>   order to remain in it.

Which means that even if you are a resident of another country for tax purposes, you are still tax resident of Argentina:

- if  the  individual  has  its  permanent  dwelling  in  the 
  Argentine  Republic  (a  suitable  facility  currently used for
  living or available for the main end of housing); or
- if its centre of vital interest is located within the national territory (in which
  he/she has its closest personal and economic relationships, mainly
  the personal ones); or
- if  the  individual  permanently  resides  in the  Argentine 
  Republic,  a  condition  that  will  be  considered fulfilled if the
  person remains there more time than the one spent in the foreign
  State which granted the permanent residence, or which considers
  them as residents for tax purposes during the calendar year); and if they are of Argentine nationality.

If you are looking for Permanent Residence or Citizenship status of another country without living at the other country, you can try [OECD - Residence/Citizenship by investment schemes](https://www.oecd.org/tax/automatic-exchange/crs-implementation-and-assistance/residence-citizenship-by-investment/).

Comment: Do all four conditions have to be satisfied in order for Argentina to agree that one is not a tax resident, or does Argentina consider its citizens to be tax residents regardless of where they live? The latter is s the rule, for example,  in the US: US citizens are US tax residents and must file a US tax return regardless of where they might be domiciled or where else they might be taxed. There are, of course, rules in the US Tax Code which eliminate _double_ taxation in many cases.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I looked at the Law itself (Decree 649/97) and saw that Art. 125 says the fourth condition is tied to the 3rd condition, so 123 is OR, 34 is AND. http://servicios.infoleg.gob.ar/infolegInternet/anexos/40000-44999/44911/texact.htm